# Spring Boot Micrometer Hierarchical Metric Namespace Concatenation

Tags: graphite, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a Spring Boot Java app and am sending metrics to a hierarchical Graphite metrics system. I'm using the management.metrics.export.graphite.tags-as-prefix and mapping host and app to prefix my metrics. I then have a metric with namespace `jvm.memory.committed`, but the metric namespace is coming over the wire as `host.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.*`. So it's replacing dots (".") in the metric namespace and camelCasing the following piece of the namespace.

application.properties
`management.metrics.export.graphite.tags-as-prefix=[host, app]`

Customizer for tags as prefix.

```
    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> commonTags() {
        return r -> r.config().commonTags("host", "localhost", "app", "app");
    }
```

When I look at the .../actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed endpoint I see the following:

```
  "name": "jvm.memory.committed",
  "description": "The amount of memory in bytes that is committed for the Java virtual machine to use",
  "baseUnit": "bytes",
  "measurements": [
    {
      "statistic": "VALUE",
      "value": 759701504
    }
  ],
  "availableTags": [
    {
      "tag": "area",
      "values": [
        "heap",
        "nonheap"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "app",
      "values": [
        "app"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "host",
      "values": [
        "localhost"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "id",
      "values": [
        "G1 Old Gen",
        "CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'",
        "G1 Survivor Space",
        "Compressed Class Space",
        "Metaspace",
        "G1 Eden Space",
        "CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'"
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

However, when the metrics are being sent with the metric names changed from `*.jvm.memory.committed.*` to `*.jvmMemoryCommitted.*`. How can I preserve the metrics namespace in dot-notation?

See the tcpdump output below:

````
$ sudo tcpdump -i any -A -s0 -vv udp port 2003 | grep -i committed
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
....E....5..@............E...p..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.heap.id.G1_Eden_Space 178257920.00 1628102627
....E....5..@............E...p..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.heap.id.G1_Eden_Space 178257920.00 1628102627
....E...o...@............E...m..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.heap.id.G1_Old_Gen 465567744.00 1628102627
....E...o...@............E...m..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.heap.id.G1_Old_Gen 465567744.00 1628102627
....E.......@............E...s..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.heap.id.G1_Survivor_Space 10485760.00 1628102627
....E.......@............E...s..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.heap.id.G1_Survivor_Space 10485760.00 1628102627
....E...m...@............E...{..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.CodeHeap_'non-nmethods' 3604480.00 1628102627
....E...m...@............E...{..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.CodeHeap_'non-nmethods' 3604480.00 1628102627
....E....J..@............E......localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.CodeHeap_'non-profiled_nmethods' 10420224.00 1628102627
....E....J..@............E......localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.CodeHeap_'non-profiled_nmethods' 10420224.00 1628102627
....E.......@............E...z..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.Compressed_Class_Space 9306112.00 1628102627
....E.......@............E...z..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.Compressed_Class_Space 9306112.00 1628102627
....E....,..@............E...n..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.Metaspace 69607424.00 1628102627
....E....,..@............E...n..localhost.app.jvmMemoryCommitted.area.nonheap.id.Metaspace 69607424.00 1628102627
^C444 packets captured
3200 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel```

I think the problem is that I'm using tags, but in a Hierarchical metrics system, but I can't figure out how to configure it properly. I can't seem to find my folly.

Spring Boot 2.5.2
Micrometer Core and Micrometer Registry Graphite 1.7.2
````

Comment: You were detailed in your question setup, but I can't tell what the exact question is. Can you state what you expect to happen and what isn't happening?

Comment: @checketts I've edited the post slightly. Sorry for the ambiguity. My question is how I can preserve the metric name in dot-notation as is typical for hierarchical metrics rather than the  dot-notation getting camelCase'd. After thinking on it, I removed the MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> bean that I had and tried creating a bean GraphiteMeterRegiry bean as shown in the documentation below. With that I no longer see any prefix and the dot-notation to camelCase is still happening.
https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/graphite#_prefixing_your_metrics

Answer (score 1):

Graphite uses a `HierarchicalNameMapper` to convert the metric names and tags into a hierarchical string.

See https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/graphite#_hierarchical_name_mapping

I'm not certain why you mapper is camelCasing your metric name, but you can set the `HierarchicalNameMapper` when you construct your own `GraphiteMeterRegistry` and have fine tuned control of how they are generated.